# Xamarin List<> not updating UI

Tags: c#, xamarin

I wanted to try toggling a series of StackLayout's IsVisible property using a list of boolean. To better elaborate, here are my codes:

**View**

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding pageVisible[0]}">
                <Label Text="Page 1"/>
                <Button Text="Next"
                        Command="{Binding ToNextCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding currentPage}"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding pageVisible[1]}">
                <Label Text="Page 2"/>
                <Button Text="Next"
                        Command="{Binding ToNextCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding currentPage}"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding pageVisible[2]}">
               <Label Text="Page 3"/>
               <Button Text="Next"
                       Command="{Binding ToNextCommand}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding currentPage}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**View Model**

```
        private List<bool> _pageVisible;
        public List<bool> pageVisible 
        { 
            get => _pageVisible;
            set
            {
                _pageVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ProfileCompletionViewModel()
        {
            pageVisible = new List<bool>();
            pageVisible.Add(true); //to make the first stacklayout visible

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                pageVisible.Add(false);
            }
        }
        public ICommand ToNextCommand { get; }
        private int _currentPage = 0;
        public int currentPage
        {
            get => _currentPage;
            set => SetProperty(ref _currentPage, value);
        }
        private async Task ToNextFunc()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                pageVisible[i] = false; //Set all to false
            pageVisible[_currentPage + 1] = true;
            currentPage += 1;
        }
    }
```

The list is updating well when I clicked 'Next' (I found out using breakpoints). But the View is not updating despite having OnPropertyChange() on the List. Is there something wrong in my codes? T_T

Thank you in advance

Comment: Each element of psgeVisible needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which won’t work since you are using value types.  You would be better off using three distinct bool properties that each raise PropertyChanged

Comment: @Jason I see, I just tried if it will work with a minimal line of code. I guess I need to give each a separate property. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> I see, I just tried if it will work with a minimal line of code. I
> guess I need to give each a separate property.

Yes, you can define several separate variables for each property,
but you can also create a model for the item of the list and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` .

I create a demo to simulate this function, it works properly on my side. You can refer to the following code:

1.create a class `Item` for the list item.

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private bool _pageVisible;
        public bool PageVisible
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _pageVisible, value); }
            get { return _pageVisible; }
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
 public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        public  List<Item> pageVisibleList { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            pageVisibleList = new List<Item>();
            pageVisibleList.Add( new Item { PageVisible = true}); //to make the first stacklayout visible

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                pageVisibleList.Add(new Item { PageVisible = false });
            }

        }
        public ICommand ToNextCommand => new Command(ToNextFunction);

        private void ToNextFunction()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                pageVisibleList[i].PageVisible = false; //Set all to false

            if (_currentPage < 2)
            {
                pageVisibleList[_currentPage + 1].PageVisible= true;
            }
            else {
                _currentPage = 0;
                pageVisibleList[0].PageVisible = true;
            }
            currentPage += 1;
        }

        private int _currentPage = 0;
        public int currentPage
        {
            get => _currentPage;
            set => SetProperty(ref _currentPage, value);
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:app1109="clr-namespace:App1109"
             x:Class="App1109.TestPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app1109:MyViewModel></app1109:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding pageVisibleList[0].PageVisible}">
                <Label Text="Page 1"/>
                <Button Text="Next --> Button 1"
                        Command="{Binding ToNextCommand}"
                        />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding pageVisibleList[1].PageVisible}">
                <Label Text="Page 2"/>
                <Button Text="Next  --> Button 2"
                        Command="{Binding ToNextCommand}"
                        />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding pageVisibleList[2].PageVisible}">
                <Label Text="Page 3"/>
                <Button Text="Next --> Button 3"
                       Command="{Binding ToNextCommand}"
                       />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```